# WordPress 403 Forbidden when updating WooCommerce product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Recently when I wanted to updated a specific product on my WordPress, I receive "403 Forbidden" error right after I click "Update" blue button.
There are several similar questions on both StackOverflow and WordPress Exchange but most of them happened just because they added code or it happens right after installing WordPress.
In this case here, I haven't made any specific change before making new changes. I published the product about a year ago and now I can't update it! I can't even private it to publish a newer version!
For this specific product, I used **Attributes** and **Variations**. I even checked related **Brand**, **Attributes**, **Tags** and **Categories** and I found no issue with any of them. All images, brands, attributes and anything else related to this product are accessible and public.
I know I should give deeper details and information but unfortunately, WordPress doesn't give me any more information that why this happens and what is wrong exactly with this product.
What I'm worry right now is that there can be many other product with this problem and I don't even know what to do with them now!

**UPDATE:** I've done more investigations and I realized that whatever styles I apply such as **"H1", "H2", "H3", "H4"**, it redirects me to **403 Forbidden** page!
This happens ONLY for two available products.
If anybody here any any possible solution for this problem, please helps me and comments below. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved!
I found out that author has used this **(¾”)** weird thing somewhere in descriptions and yes, it couldn't save this "¾" in database.